# How can I store this log data in database

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a `log file` from firewall, and I want to store it in `mysql` database using `php`, I have used the same key for database,  I want to `separate` the log data in `array key=value` format and again there is `space` between each key values, and there are some `countries` which contain spaces between the coutry name. So how can I complete my task. And for the idea here you can see the log file:

```
 date=2016-04-11 time=11:26:29 logid=0000000013 type=traffic
 subtype=forward level=notice vd=root srcip=10.10.24.232 srcport=35321
 srcintf="port2" dstip=173.252.74.22 dstport=443 dstintf="wan1"
 poluuid=426a22f0-b2d8-51e5-4e06-b3d158ed335f sessionid=11469008
 proto=6 action=deny policyid=33 dstcountry="United States"
 srccountry="Reserved" trandisp=snat transip=202.166.220.127
 transport=35321 service="HTTPS" appid=15832 app="Facebook"
 appcat="Social.Media" apprisk=medium applist="GEN-ACC-FBBLK"
 appact=drop-session duration=22 sentbyte=120 rcvdbyte=60 sentpkt=2
 utmaction=block countapp=1 utmref=62972-2591658 date=2016-04-11
 time=11:26:29 logid=0000000013 type=traffic subtype=forward
 level=notice vd=root srcip=10.10.37.60 srcport=43857 srcintf="port2"
 dstip=202.166.193.187 dstport=443 dstintf="wan1"
 poluuid=426a22f0-b2d8-51e5-4e06-b3d158ed335f sessionid=11373387
 proto=6 action=close policyid=33 dstcountry="Nepal"
 srccountry="Reserved" trandisp=snat transip=202.166.220.127
 transport=43857 service="HTTPS" appid=41542 app="SSL_TLSv1.0"
 appcat="Network.Service" apprisk=medium applist="GEN-ACC-FBBLK"
 appact=detected duration=424 sentbyte=1320 rcvdbyte=1582 sentpkt=10
 rcvdpkt=16 utmaction=allow countapp=2 utmref=62972-2591632
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? Have you tried something? Show us what you've tried, then we will be able to help you to improve/fix your code.

Comment: I tried it using explode function first but not getting what I need, you can try the log file reading .

Comment: Then show us this code. Show us what you get that is not what you expect. The logs you show us, how do you get it in php? Is it in a variable? a string? In an array? In short, give us more information!

Comment: It's a log file and I upload it manually for my record as I have posted the log example in above question I just explode it using but I am not getting the correct format. What I want to do is I will make the date is field name and value is value in database too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can correct it myself, I hope it will help to others too:

```
$str = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$str1 = str_replace("\"", "", ($str) );

$vals=split('date=', $str1);
array_shift($vals);

$finalArray = array();
$j = 0;
foreach($vals as $v){
    $finalArray[$j]["date"] = substr($v, 0, 10);
    //var_dump($v);
    $tempString = substr($v, 11);

    $tempArr = explode(" ", $tempString);
    $prevTemp = "";
    foreach($tempArr as $i){
        $tmp = explode("=",$i);
        if(!isset($tmp[1])){
            $finalArray[$j][$prevTemp] = $finalArray[$j][$prevTemp]." ".$i;
        }
        else{
            $finalArray[$j][$tmp[0]] = isset($tmp[1]) ? $tmp[1]: '';
            $prevTemp = $tmp[0];
        }

    }
    $j++;
}
//var_dump($finalArray);
//die();


$totalQuery = '';
foreach($finalArray as $val){
    if(is_array($val)){
        $queryText = 'INSERT INTO `intrulog` SET';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($val as $k=>$v){
            if(isset($v) && !empty($v)){
                if($i)
                    $queryText .= ',';
                $queryText .= " `{$k}` = '{$v}' ";
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $queryText .= ";<br>";

        $totalQuery .= $queryText; 
    }
}
//echo $queryText;
}
```